# How do === and == handle null comparisons differently?

Tags: javascript, string, json, comparison

I have a simple json parsed object that sometimes has a variable `tt` defined and sometimes doesn't.

For some reason `jsonobject.tt == null` returns correctly `1` or `0` based on whether `tt` is defined. `jasonobject.tt === null` just returns `0` regardless. I thought `===` was the thing to use to avoid issues.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`===` is the strict equality operator, it compares type as well as value. The value `null` is the Null Type that has exactly one value - `null`.

Undefined is the Undefined Type, which also has only one value - 'undefined'.

When using the strict equality operator, null !== undefined because they are different types (see step 1 of the Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm, ECMA-262 § 11.9.6).

`==` is the equality operator. Comparisons using `==` use the Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm (ECMA-262 § 11.9.3), which includes:

> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then ...
> 2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.

So `null == undefined` returns true by definition. Strictly, testing for the presence of a property (regardless of its value), should use *hasOwnProperty*:

```
if (jsonobject.hasOwnProperty('tt')) {
  // property exists
}
```

however in practice there isn't much difference to a strict test for *undefined*:

```
if (jsonobject.tt === undefined)
```

because whether the property exists and has a value of *undefined* or hasn't been defined at all is usually equivalent. Using `===` also means that the above will return false if *tt* exists but has been assigned a value of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason (jsonobject.tt == null) returns correctly 1 or 0

Firstly a comparison returns `true` or `false`

Secondly you want

`jsonobject.tt === undefined`

If a value does not exist it is undefined.

Other detection methods are

`!jsonobject.hasOwnProperty("tt");`

or

`!("tt" in jsonobject)`

As a side effect of `==` being a totally weird operator, `null == undefined`. Thus `jsonobject.tt == null` will return true if the property is not there

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Sneaky updating your answer while I added my comment.

Comment: I'm aware that posting a short snippet as an answer gets you top of the "oldest" list and therefor is likely to net more votes; which is largely the reason I disapprove of the practice.

Comment: @zzzzBov I prefer to see it as streaming an answer. Except stackoverflow.com does not have the architecture in place for streaming answers

Comment: It just makes it difficult to comment on things when versioning isn't provided for early revisions.

Comment: Good that you mentioned `.hasOwnProperty()` and the `in` operator: I think these are better choices in general because they let you distinguish between when a property doesn't exist at all and when a property does exist but has the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable hasn't been defined it has a value of `undefined`.

```
undefined == null
```

whereas

```
undefined !== null
```